# Regeneration Energy Used for Healing

Tags: doctor-who, time-lord, regeneration

In *The Angels Take Mahattan* (S07E05)

> The Doctor uses his regeneration energy to heal River's wrist.

Has regeneration energy ever been used to heal another Timelord (or anyone else for that matter)?

Excluding the time

> River heals the Doctor after nearly killing him in *Let's Kill Hitler* (S06E08)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sort of stunt was first mentioned in Mawdryn Undead, quoting form the wikipedia [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regeneration_%28Doctor_Who%29#Transference_of_regenerative_energy):

> In Mawdryn Undead (1983), it is first referenced that a Time Lord could transfer his regenerative life essence to another being. **In that story, the Fifth Doctor is coerced by Mawdryn to give up his future regenerations in order to cure Nyssa and Tegan Jovanka from Mawdryn 's disease**.

This transfer never happens, though it's clear that it can be used for various regenerative purposes, such as curing fatal diseases.

> It is not until "Let's Kill Hitler" (2011) that such a transference is shown. In that instance, **River sacrifices her own regenerative power in order to save the Eleventh Doctor**.... The favour is returned in "The Angels Take Manhattan" where **River Song's wrist is repaired by the Doctor**, who subsequently gives up a portion of his regenerative energy.

It's unclear, at this point, how much this cost the Doctor's regenerative energy, though River scolds him for his actions, perhaps showing it may have future repercussions.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is the first occurance. I believe it was possible as it is the same energy that she gave him in **Let's Kill Hitler**, and her unique physiology otherwise it raises interesting questions about all the times The Doctor has been unable to help people he could've theoretically healed.

Comment: the more interesting question IMO is why River got so angry over it, as if The Doctor was using up a finite resource.